# GetByteArrayRegion in JNI

Tags: java, c, java-native-interface, byte

The question is:
Suppose I use the function:
(* env) -> GetByteArrayRegion (env, array, 0, len, (jbyte *)buf);
In this case, a certain number of bytes written from the array to the buf or vice versa? Maybe a simple question, but I'm confused. Help, please:. In the documentation is not found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Get <PrimitiveTypeArray>ArrayRegion` is a family of functions that copies a region of a primitive array into a buffer. That's what the documentation says. It seems clear to me.

Comment: Is there a function to copy the contrary PART of jbyte to jbyteArray?

Comment: @Kyborg2011: yes, Set<PrimitiveType>ArrayRegion(). It's the next API in the JNI specification after Get<PrimitiveType>ArrayRegion().

Comment: Adding link to documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html